# Grails 3.3.0 M1 and 3.3.0 M2 Combining MongoDB and Hibernate fail

Tags: mongodb, hibernate, grails

Step1: use command create app

```
grails create-app test
```

Step2: create domain

```
grails create-domain-class test
```

Step3: configue build.gradle

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:mongodb'
```

Step4: configue application.yml

```
grails:
   mongodb:
       host: "localhost"
       port: 27017
       username: ""
       password: ""
       databaseName: "test"
environments:
development:
    dataSource:
        dbCreate: none
        url:jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
        logSql: true
```

Step5: use mapWith in Test.groovy

```
static mapWith="mongo"
```

Step6: query test in bootstrap

```
println Test.findAll()
```

Stop7: run grails app

```
grails run-app
```

the error is :

```
 org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: Hibernate operation: could not prepare statement; bad SQL grammar [select this_.id as id1_0_0_, this_.version as version2_0_0_ from test this_]; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "TEST" not found; SQL statement:
select this_.id as id1_0_0_, this_.version as version2_0_0_ from test this_ [42102-194]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:231)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.convertJdbcAccessException(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:723)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.convertHibernateAccessException(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:711)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.doExecute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:302)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:242)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:116)
        at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateGormStaticApi.list(HibernateGormStaticApi.groovy:74)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.findAll(GormStaticApi.groovy:579)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.findAll(GormEntity.groovy:671)
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper$findAll$0.call(Unknown Source)
```

use other version :

- 3.2.3 is OK
- 3.2.5 is OK
- 3.2.9 is Ok

My code is :
[the demo in github](https://github.com/halfray/TestGrailsWithMongo)

what change in 3.3.0.M1 and 3.3.0.M2 ?

Comment: Show your full `application.yml` code

Comment: you can see it : [application.yml](https://github.com/halfray/TestGrailsWithMongo/blob/master/grails-app/conf/application.yml)

Comment: before 3.3.0,when create  DefaultGrailsDomainClass for domain class ,will set mappingStrategy use mapWith field ,but now it is not do that ,it is a bug?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me

Comment: I created an issue for you https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/issues/957

Answer (score 0):

```
grails:
    mongodb:
       host: "localhost"
       port: 27017
       username: ""
       password: ""
       databaseName: "test"

environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: none
            url: jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
            logSql: true
    test:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    production:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: none
            url: jdbc:h2:./prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
            properties:
                jmxEnabled: true
                initialSize: 5
                maxActive: 50
                minIdle: 5
                maxIdle: 25
                maxWait: 10000
                maxAge: 600000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                validationQuery: SELECT 1
                validationQueryTimeout: 3
                validationInterval: 15000
                testOnBorrow: true
                testWhileIdle: true
                testOnReturn: false
                jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
                defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

Replace your these lines to this

```
environments:
    development:
        grails:
            mongodb:
                host: "localhost"
                port: 27017
                username: ""
                password: ""
                databaseName: "test"
    test:
        mongodb:
                host: "localhost"
                port: 27017
                username: ""
                password: ""
                databaseName: "test"
    production:
        grails:
            mongodb:
                host: "localhost"
                port: 27017
                username: ""
                password: ""
                databaseName: "test"
            properties:
                jmxEnabled: true
                initialSize: 5
                maxActive: 50
                minIdle: 5
                maxIdle: 25
                maxWait: 10000
                maxAge: 600000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                validationQuery: SELECT 1
                validationQueryTimeout: 3
                validationInterval: 15000
                testOnBorrow: true
                testWhileIdle: true
                testOnReturn: false
                jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
                defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

Comment: if i only want use mongo ,just need remove  `compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"` from build.gradle ,but in my project, i need Combining MongoDB and Hibernate